# How to extend JavaDoc 5.0 standard doclet?

Tags: java, javadoc, doclet

I want to extend the standard doclet provided by Javadoc5.0 to modify its HTML output. For example I want to replace the keyword 'implemented' or 'Interfaces' with another word whenever it occurs within the generated JavaDoc HTML. All other elements should not be changed. How can I achieve this? I do not want to modify the HTML source after the Javadoc is generated! Which Classes I have to extend? Is there a useful tutorial in the net? I searched for tutorials but found only this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/javadoc/doclet/overview.html which does not help me very much since the examples don't extend the standard doclet. Found another source on http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#customizingjavadoc but I cannot apply this to JavaDoc5.0. Can anybody provide a useful example?
Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you already see Doxygen? [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org)

It could be a great alternative to javadoc and it is free and customizable.
I think that it could help you.
I hope to have helped you.