# How to change output of the standard doclet?

Tags: doclet

I would like to slightly modify the output of the standard doclet. I don't want however to write my own new doclet, because my changes are not really big.

I have looked for tutorials, but found only those for creating new doclets. There is no answer here either:

[How to tweak the standard doclet--not write an entirely-new doclet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21555411/how-to-tweak-the-standard-doclet-not-write-an-entirely-new-doclet)

[How to extend JavaDoc 5.0 standard doclet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20121382/how-to-extend-javadoc-5-0-standard-doclet)

How can I achieve modified output?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please post some of the code snippets you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found source files that I can modify here:

https://jdk7.java.net/source.html

standard doclet is in openjdk/langtools/src/share/classes/com/sun/tools/doclets